# Parentheses auto-completion in TeXStudio 4.7.3

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

There was a way to disable parentheses autocompletion in TeXStudio 10 years ago. It does not work anymore. Do they still give this option in the current version?
I usually put parentheses around text only after the text it written, so I struggle with all these double parentheses.

Comment: Options / Configure TeXstudio / Show Advanced Options / Adv. Editor / Auto Complete Parentheses

Comment: I got it! I check "show advanced options". Then there appears Advanced Editor on the left, not in the right part. I select this Advanced Editor option, then there is option for autocomplete parentheses!

Comment: Thank you! You answered my question.